# php \r and \n same thing?

Tags: php

Why have 2 functions that does the same thing? They both add a linebreak.

Any diffrence between them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP, and is a consequence of history :

- UNIX / Linux use `\n` for linebreaks
- Mac *(before OSX)* used `\r`
- And windows uses a combinaison of both

PHP has just kept that behavior -- so it can work with those different OSes and their files.

Also, note :

- Those are not functions : they are (special) characters
- They are not exactly the same thing :

  - `\r` is [Carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)
  - `\n` is [Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)
- and, btw, those are another consequence of history : look at their names, and think about [typewriters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter) ;-)

Comment: Only Mac OS until 9 used `\r`; Mac OS X uses `\n`.

Comment: @Gumbo : didn't know that (but makes sense, as OSX is based on BSD) ; I edited my answer to reflect your note ;; thanks !

Comment: @Frederik : no, I edited my answer -- once again, I learnt something while giving an answer ^^ (And that's great ! )

Comment: @Fredrik If you edit your answer soon enough after posting, SO doesn't show the *EDITED* box. @Pascal edited his answer in response to @Gumbo's feedback.

Comment: @Doug, @Pascal: So I noticed, that is why I removed the comment.