# ^M at end of lines when editing in CodeBlocks (I think)

Tags: windows, linux, vim, newline, codeblocks

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 10.04. I use vim for most of my development and CodeBlocks for debugging. When I first moved from Windows to Linux, I noticed that vim was showing ^Ms for newlines, and found out that this was a Microsoft thing. However, even after removing them I notice that they sometimes reappear in files (files that I edit in CodeBlocks I think?).

Am I analyzing this correctly? How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are indeed caused by windows-style ends of lines.

For more informations, see, for example : [php \r and \n same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018668/php-r-and-n-same-thing/2018678#2018678)

The only way to avoid that problem is to **configure your editor / IDE so it uses linux-style ends of lines** -- all modern / complete IDE provide a way to configure that ; I suppose CodeBlocks does too...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do [dos2unix](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm) on all those files which have been edited on the windows machines.