# php \r - print statements before and after not working

Tags: php

The print statements before and after a print statement containing a Carriage return are not working.

```
<?php
print "hello";
print " hai \r";
print "bro";
?>
```

the output is

```
bro
```

Comment: did you now what `carriage return` means?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: I googled php  \r and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018668/php-r-and-n-same-thing  just assumed i could print a newline using \r also

Comment: What i dont get here is, that `\r` not only resets the cursor position. It also deletes the printed line. And that the reason why only `bro` is left.

Comment: And if you use `\r\n` togehter, the line will stay as it was written. Thats a little tricky too understand.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions  "\r not only resets the cursor position. It also deletes the printed line"- this was the answer i wanted. You should put it up as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine, this symbol is called [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) and it's used to reset a cursor position.

So what your script is doing:

1. print a line
2. print a line and reset cursor position
3. print a line again

You see this behaviour only while running a script in console.

The better way to have a new line symbol in your code is to use a special constant PHP_EOL as it will use a proper sequence (\r or \n\r or \n) depending on a running platform.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php
print "hello";
print " hai \r\n";
print "bro";
?>
```

For a new line.

Comment: would just a \n not be enough?

Comment: \r\n are end of line characters for Windows systems.
\n is the end of line character for UNIX systems.

Comment: Use PHP_EOL for correctness on the platform we are running on.